# Why does assigning a string literal as value of a structure's character array member yield an error?

Tags: c, structure

There exists a structure I defined as follows:

```
struct details
{
    char name[20];
    int age;
    char country[20];
};
```

In this specific instance, however, declaring an object of the structure and assigning a string literal as value to either of the two character array members yields an error. The error erupts when I assign values through the following way:

```
int main()
{
    struct details d1;
    d1.name="Constantine";
    d1.country="Byzantium";
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

The error that my GCC C compiler yields is as follows:

**error: incompatible types in assignment of 'const char [12]' to 'char [20]'**

Does this occur owing to the fact that the string literal is a constant character array whereas the character array members I have declared as constituents of the said structure are not constant in nature? Would declaring the said structure members as constant resolve the error at hand? Or do I have embrace a different approach to load initial values to the said structure members?

Comment: Look at using `strncpy(dest, src, len)`.

Comment: C does not let you copy arrays with a single assignment statement.

Comment: You can't assign to an entire array at once (note that assignment != initialization).

Comment: If you want to "load initial value", you should use an initializer.  eg `struct details d1 = { .name = "Constantine", .country="Byzantium" };`

Comment: @WilliamPursell, following your method yields an error though. The compiler spits the following error message: "C99 designator 'name' outside aggregate initializer." What is causing this anomaly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C language `=` does not copy the context of the arrays. String literal is a `const char` array. To copy arrays you need to iterate through all elements of the arrays.

```
char *copy_string(char *dest, const char *src)
{
    char *wrk = dest;
    while((*wrk++ = *src++)) {}
    return dest;
}
```

As string manipulations are very common in the programming C standard library provides string manipulation functions (`strcpy`, `strlen`, `strcmp` etc etc) 'out of the box'

You can only use the assignment when you **initialize** the object. During the initialisation, the string literal will be copied into the array.

```
    struct details d1 = {.name="Constantine", .country="Byzantium"};
    char str[] = "Hello World";
    int arr[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
```